# Pass mysql_query results to foreach

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, loops

I used the following code to to get list of users facebook friends and ccheck it against users in an app database. This code would return the users of the app, who are Facebook friends of the user.

```
     $friends_set = '(';
             foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
                 $friends_set .= $value['id'].','; 
             }
             $new_set = preg_replace('/,$/',')',$friends_set);
               $res = mysql_query("SELECT * from user AS u, upload AS up WHERE u.fb_id IN $new_set AND u.fb_id=up.user_id") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

        echo $row['fb_id']. "". $row['first_name'];
        echo "<br>"; 

      }

$data['top_friends']=$res;
$this->load->view('myview');
```

This code works. It is in a controller of my codeigniter application and it successfully echos the correct data onto the page.

However now I need to print the result of the query in a for each statement in my view like this:

```
<?php foreach ($top_friends as $me) : ?>

                    <div >

                    <p><?php echo $me['first_name']; ?></p>

                     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However when I try getting the query results in the view using the for each it doesn't work.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it the codeignitor way, Create a model function say `get_top_friends` and i assume that you are passing a comma separated string as argument like $fb_id = '45,65,78,89'. Say `facebook_model` is the name of the model then :

```
class Facebook_model extends CI_Model{
     //other functions and constrcutor here

    //function to get the top friends
     function get_top_friends($fb_id){
       $fbId = explode(",",$fb_id)
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->where_in('fb_id',$fbId);
       $this->db->order_by('points','desc');
       $this->db->limit(10);
       $query = $this->db->get('user');
       if ($query->num_rows() < 1) return FALSE;
       return $query->result_array();
     }
}
```

And make change in your code as below:

```
 $friends_set = '';
     foreach($friends["data"] as $value) {
         $friends_set .= $value['id'].','; 
     }
     $new_set = preg_replace('/,$/',')',$friends_set);
     $res = $this->facebook_model->get_top_friends($new_set);
     $data['top_friends']=$res;
     $this->load->view('myview',$data);
```

And now in view you can try

```
foreach ($top_friends as $me){
  echo $me['first_name'];
}
```

[Updated for user ]

If you want to do it as in your question : then try,

```
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $result[] = $row;  
}
$data['top_friends']=$result;
$this->load->view('myview',$data);//pass data to view
```

Comment: Please see the edits to the question. previous query wasn't returning correctly, the above one does. Can the for each still work the same way with this?

Comment: Ok thanks will try. Also, I was trying to use the query in my question as a model function with active record because I need to set ` $this->db->limit($limit, $start);` to paginate the results. Or how would I set that in teh current mysql query in the controller? Where $limit is $config["per_page"], and $start is $this->uri->segment(3)

Comment: you can pass that as arguments to your model function

Comment: Yes I did pass that in other functions to get pagination in my app. However I am having trouble setting up this query as a active record function in my model as it is more complex than the others. Can you provide code for the function as you did previously. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46114/discussion-between-tester-and-nouphal-m)